# How can I use my variable only if it is defined?

Tags: php, variables, undefined, defined

I like to use `form[fieldsdata]` only if it is defined:

```
  $fieldsJson = $data["form[fieldsdata]"] ? $data["form[fieldsdata]"] : "";
```

But still the error message is:

> Notice: Undefined index: form[fieldsdata]

Comment: try to use isset()

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either use `isset()` to check if it's defined, or (if you're using PHP 7) use the null coalescing operator (??)

#### Using isset

```
$fieldsJson = isset($data["form[fieldsdata]"]) ? $data["form[fieldsdata]"] : "";
```

#### Using null-coalescing operator (PHP 7 only)

```
$fieldsJson = $data["form[fieldsdata]"] ?? "";
```

Be aware that using null coalescing will also apply the empty string  value if the index exists, but has a `null` value.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
 $fieldsJson = isset($data["form[fieldsdata]"]) ? $data["form[fieldsdata]"] : "";
```

Comment: This worked well!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Declare an array 
$array = array(); 
// Use isset function 
echo isset($array['geeks']) ? 'array is set.' : 'array is not set.';
```

Output:

```
array is not set.
```